# Prevent PySimpleGui scrollbar from moving when Listbox is populated with new data

Tags: python, pysimplegui

My PySimpleGui Listbox ("-NUMBERS-") scrollbar jumps to the top every time new data is added to the Listbox. How do I prevent this from happening? This behavior makes it very difficult to scroll and read the data in the listbox as new information is being added.

My program spawns a thread that simply adds a number to a list in the background. As the list is populated, the listbox reflects the state of the list.

```
import queue
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

import PySimpleGUI as sg

numbers_queue = queue.Queue()


def add_number_to_list(numbers_queue):
    list_nums = []

    for i in range(0, 20):
        sleep(0.5)
        list_nums.append(i)
        numbers_queue.put(list_nums)

    return

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Hello from PySimpleGUI")],
    [sg.Button("Start")],
    [sg.Listbox(values=[], enable_events=True, size=(40, 10), key="-NUMBERS-")]
]

window = sg.Window(title="Hello World", layout=layout, margins=(500, 500))

# create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

    if event == "Start":
        numbers_thread = Thread(target=add_number_to_list, args=(numbers_queue,), daemon=True)
        numbers_thread.start()

    try:
        list_of_numbers = numbers_queue.get_nowait()
    except queue.Empty:
        list_of_numbers = []

    if list_of_numbers:
        window["-NUMBERS-"].update(list_of_numbers)
```

Comment: maybe you will have to add code which scroll it down (change selection on last element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scroll_to_index=...` to scroll to last element

```
if list_of_numbers:
    last = len(list_of_numbers)
    window["-NUMBERS-"].update(list_of_numbers, scroll_to_index=last)
```

---

I would even do:

```
if not numbers_queue.empty():
    list_of_numbers = numbers_queue.get_nowait()
    last = len(list_of_numbers)
    window["-NUMBERS-"].update(list_of_numbers, scroll_to_index=last)
```